# Between operator usage in date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need this year data from one of my table, I have used between operator, But I don't want to hardcode today date in below condition, if there any way to add today date function in sql server 2008.

```
ActualDate between convert(datetime,'2015-01-01T00:00:00.000') and convert(datetime,'2015-10-23T23:59:59.997')
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see today date in your query.

Comment: qxg, I have updated my question

Comment: What is the datatype of actualDate?

Comment: @Dan : Datatype is Date

Comment: If you're working with datetime data, it's usually far better to forgo `BETWEEN` and compute an *exclusive* endpoint and use a `<` comparison for it. If you keep computing `23:59:59.997`, everything will go wrong if and when you change to using `datetime2` and timestamps have a different precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understood

```
CAST(ActualDate AS DATE) = CAST(getdate() AS DATE)
```

**UPDATE:**
and in general you can do

```
CAST(ActualDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '2015/01/01' AND CAST(getdate() AS DATE)
```

Comment: This is my requirement  select * from product where ActualDate between convert(datetime,'2015-01-01T00:00:00.000') and convert(datetime,'2015-10-23T23:59:59.997'); how can use above mentioned condition?

Comment: you tolk about today date... howewer i add another query

Comment: CAST(ActualDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '2015/01/01' AND '2015/10/23'-- I don't want like this, I need  this "CAST(ActualDate AS DATE) BETWEEN '2014/11/01' AND sysdate"

Comment: the question are poor... now is ok?

Comment: It might be working for you but that approach will have performance issues because you are filtering on function results instead of fields.

Answer (score 0):

In TSQL, today date comes from `GETDATE()` as in

```
SELECT GETDATE()
```